# How to set the default langage in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, localization

I have an app with 3 langages, `Base`, `French` and `English`.

The app displays in `French` when I set the iOS7 langage to `Italian`

Why is the app considering `French` as the default langage ?
How to change that to `English` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens :

- I set the iPhone langage to Italian
- The OS doesn't find Italian localization in my app
- Then it checks my iPhone region : "France"
- The app is displayed in French

When I change the region to Italy, the langage falls back to English.

Answer (score 0):

1. Access your target by clicking on your project.
2. Switch to the *Info*
   pane.
3. Within *Custom iOS Target Properties*, check the value for the
   entry *Localization native development region*.
4. You can set it to ***en*** or choose from the suggested list.

[image: screen capture]